# Unexpected result of select in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am having trouble understanding why one of the columns from the SELECT results returns 0. I am trying to inner join Table 1 and 2. The column "Time2" has a similar query to Time3 in Table 1. This is the query I have:

```
SELECT [ID] AS [ID1],
       [RESULT.CurrentDate] AS [CurrentDate],
       strftime("%j", substr([RESULT.CurrentDate], 1, instr([RESULT.CurrentDate], ' ') - 1) ) AS Time3,
       b.Time2,
       [ID2],
       [No],
       Date,
       abs(b.Time2 - Time3) AS Time4
  FROM Table1 a
       INNER JOIN
       Table2 b ON a.[ID1] = b.[ID2] AND 
                abs(b.Time2 - Time3) < 7
```

Here are some of the results returned:

```
ID1     CurrentDate                    Time Time2  ID2          No    Date                Time4
001   2019-11-07 12:21:17           311 296   001   1817    2019-10-23 11:42:27 0
001   2019-11-07 12:21:17           311 311   001   2309    2019-11-07 17:07:13 0
002   2019-11-07 12:21:43           311 296   002   1808    2019-10-23 11:52:59 0
002   2019-11-07 12:21:43           311 311   002   2329    2019-11-07 17:19:16 0
003   2019-11-07 12:22:19           311 296   003   1835    2019-10-23 10:57:17 0
003   2019-11-07 12:22:19           311 311   003   2321    2019-11-07 17:29:48 0
```

I do not understand why (`b.Time2 - Time3`) is 0? I expected, it should be 15 and 0 per row. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite there is no Datetime data type.
Any value like `2019-11-07 12:21:17` is considered as `TEXT`, so when you try to subtract, say:

```
'2019-11-07 12:21:17' - '2019-11-06 10:20:10'
```

what SQLite does is to try to convert each of the values to a numeric value starting from its 1st char and moving to the right until a non numeric char is reached.
So the result is:

```
2019 - 2019
```

and you get `0`, because in both dates the valid numeric part starting from the left is `2019`.
If you want to subtract dates in SQLite, use [`julianday()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
julianday(b.Time2) - julianday(Time3)
```

which will return the difference in days (with a decimal part).
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRq1Ynn5GN2SdECB4e48ge/0).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of why the results returns 0. Everything is clear now!